# DWM: Switch two windows places | Move windows

Tags: dwm

I just got a quick question regarding `dwm`, how can I switch the places of two windows, so window A is switched with window B or is it even possible to move windows around?

Because I just like to have my main windows open up on the left side of the screen, so I can easily look at them.
The problem is that they sometimes move to the right side.

Thanks in advance, I would really appreciate your help with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out myself, by default mod + Return switches the master and stack.

Answer (score 0):

To move a windows in DWM:
Hold your *modkey* + left mouse button